# Can't see result set in MySQLWorkbench, Mac OS Catalina

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench, macos-catalina

I can't see my result set after executing a query in MySQLWorkbench (8.0), I'm operating on Mac OS Catalina

Comment: I can't see the query after reading this.

Comment: please share Image if possible.

Comment: Try to resize the bottom sections. Results section height might have been reduced to 0.

Comment: I tried resizing, doesn't seem to work, tried reinstalling older versions, also not working

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and it turns out the problem was that the **font** I had configured for the result set was no longer available after the OS update, and there seems to be no font fallback mechanism in MySQLWorkbench, so it failed to render anything.

The solution for me was to go to `MySQLWorkbench > Preferences > Fonts` and type in `Helvetica 13` as the value of `Resultset Grid`.

You may also choose to also change the fonts for the other options like `SQL Editor` if you have trouble with the display of other sections of the app. And you are free to choose any other font family, as long as it’s actually installed on your machine.

If you put in an invalid value into any of those fields, you may need to restart the app to recover from the resulting display error. And note that changes to those font settings are only applied to new instances of the related UI widgets, so you have to request a **new** result set in order to see the changes.